# How to choose correct collation to create database when migrating Postgres from Windows to Linux using pg_dump?

Tags: postgresql, collation, pg-dump, pg-restore

I have below configuration in my source window database

| Name | Owner | Encoding | Collate | Ctype | Access privileges |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| sourcedb | appuser | UTF8 | English_South Africa.1252 | English_South Africa.1252 |  |

I want to know how to check what is the equivalent collation when I migrate to Linux.
I feel `en_ZA.UTF-8` as the equivalent. Need guidance if this is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `en_ZA.UTF-8` would be the proper locale.

Make sure it is defined on your system using `locale -a`. If it doesn't show up, you have to configure it in a way that depends on your Linux distribution.